# ¿como copiar una celda a otra en phpmyadmin?

Tags: python, phpmyadmin, tkinter, mariadb

Estoy intentando buscar la solución a este problema, espero y me puedan ayudar.
Tengo dos tablas en phpmyadmin (MariaDB) una nombrada "ingresos" y otra "movimientos", lo que quiero es copiar el folio de "ingresos" en la tabla de "movimientos" respetando el AUTO_INCREMENT y UNSIGNED ZEROFILL

Tabla de ingresos:
Lo subrayado es lo que quiero copiar en la otra tabla de igual manera subrayada.

[image: Tabla de ingresos]

Tabla de movimientos: en lo subrayado quiero que me sustituya este folio por el de ingresos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso python TK para colocar mis registros en las dos tablas.

```
def registrar_pago(self):
    datos=(self.unidad_buscar.get(), self.mz_buscar.get(), self.lt_buscar.get(), self.vi_buscar.get(), self.nombre_buscar.get(), self.metodo_buscar.get(), self.fechaing_buscar.get(), self.ref_buscar.get(), self.monto_buscar.get(), self.monto_buscar2.get(), self.registro_buscar.get(), self.clave_buscar.get(),self.idppto_buscar.get(),self.concepto_buscar.get())
    datos2=(self.clave_buscar.get(), self.fechaing_buscar.get(), self.nombre_buscar.get(), self.concepto_buscar.get(), self.idppto_buscar.get(), self.monto_buscar.get(), self.monto_buscar2.get(), self.registro_buscar.get())

    
    self.articulo2.bdi(datos,datos2)
```

Eso lo hago para que al registrar, me lo registre en las dos tablas, el problema es que me generan folios diferentes y lo que busco es que ambos folios concuerden ya que posteriormente colocare otra tabla y los folios ya no van a hacer los mismos al momento de realizar la busqueda.

Espero y me puedan auxiliar.
Saludos y gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está el query genérico para poder copiar el conjunto de datos X que están en una columna de la tabla A en otra tabla B y tomando en cuenta que los ids o identificadores del conjunto de datos X están en la columna id de la tabla A cuya columna identificadora se llama igualmente id en la tabla B:

```
UPDATE TablaB
       INNER JOIN TablaA
          ON TablaA.Id = TablaB.Id
    SET TablaB.datosX = TablaA.datosX
```

De lo anterior:

```
TablaB  = destino.
TablaA  =  origen
DatosX = la columna que se desea copiar
```

Éxitos

Fuente: https://pathros.blogspot.com/2014/01/mysql-copiar-datos-de-una-columna-de.html